# New to jQuery, ajax not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am very new to jQuery, and I am probably doing this wrong, but here is my problem. I have a page where a user puts input into boxes and hits submit, where response data will be generated on the server and sent back with AJAX. However, nothing happens when I press submit... I know the function is being called, so I think my jQuery code is wrong.

Here is my code, simplified:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#hide {
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(doAjax());
});
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        data:"myquerystring",
        url:"dummy.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#hide").css("display","inline");
        $("#result").html(data);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter your text:</p>
<!--Code for textboxes-->
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<p id="hide">Result:<pre id="result"></pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now, dummy.php is just:

```
<?php
echo "hi";
?>
```

so that's not the problem. Can anyone help me with this?

UPDATE: Chrome tells me:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'
```

when i try to run doAjax()

Comment: I don't understand... I do include the jquery.js file in the html, it is just not shown here.

Comment: Have you checked your server logs to see if `dummy.php` is getting called? Anything in your JavaScript console? BTW, `onClick` attributes are pretty old school, `$('#submit').click(function() {...})` would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working on my test. Make sure your jquery is version 1.5+ http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

[Jquery 1.5](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/)

Comment: How would I check my jquery version?

Comment: the version should be in the jquery file. :)

Comment: i suggest you download the latest version http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: that's strange. Does your page refreshes when you click the button?

Comment: It seems your jquery file is not being called. Check your view source and click the jquery link if it's pointing to the right path.

Comment: nope. i have now switched my code to use jquery click() activation rather than onClick

Comment: is it live or in your localhost?

Comment: please note, this website is not up and running at all

Comment: Your jQuery file is jQuery 1.4.4 http://resources.benspitz.com/jQuery/jquery.js. Update it to 1.5 like these good people have mentioned, and `done` should be available to you.

Comment: your jquery version is jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.4.

Comment: one more thing.. the ajax seems to be running as soon as i load the page... what can I do about this? Nevermind, got it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I usually do it. I prefer this way over the shorthand functions.

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        data:"myquerystring",
        url:"dummy.php"
        success: function(data){
            $("#hide").css("display","inline");
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.done() was introduced in jQuery 1.5.

This works since jQuery version 1.0 and is my preferred method:

```
$.get("dummy.php", {key1: "myquerystring"}, function(data) {
    $("#hide").css("display","inline");
    $("#result").html(data);
});
```

Replace {key1: "myquerystring"} with an object of key/value pairs from the querystring. `.ajax()` works this way too. I noticed you just had a string.

`.ajax()` also has a callback feature, but `.get()` is nice and short.