# jQuery Ajax function returns error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I keep getting an error when using jQuery's ajax function:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'done'

What's confusing me is it was working perfectly for the last 3 days. And I made some changes so I guess it must be my fault but its not returning a syntax error, like its telling me that the jquery ajax function is wrong, that cant be?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/cms.php",
    data: {
        job: 'edit_staff',
        id: id,
        name: staff_name,
        description: staff_description
    }
}).done(function(returned)
{
    var message = 
    $('<div class = "edit_status_message_fees">' + '<span>Success: </span>' + returned + '</div>');
    message.appendTo('.edit_team');

    $('.edit_status_message_fees')
    .fadeIn('normal',
    function()
    {
        if(returned == "Database updated!")
        {
            $.post('ajax/get_new_staff_details.php', function(new_team)
            {
                $('.theteam').html(new_team); // Update main content area
            });

            $('.edit_team')
            .delay('500')
            .fadeOut('normal', function()
            {
                $('.edit_team').remove();
            })

            $('.list_team')
            .delay('500')
            .fadeOut('normal', function()
            {
                $('.list_team').remove();
            })

            $('.edit_cover')
            .delay('500')
            .fadeOut('normal', function()
            {
                $('.edit_team').remove();
            })
        }

    })
}); // END ajax
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers, or only in IE?

Comment: Also, [as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360522/new-to-jquery-ajax-not-working), make sure you're using a jQuery version of 1.5 or above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using an older jQuery version, upgrade it, or do something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "ajax/cms.php",

      ...

      complete: function() { 
        //your callback body
      }
});
```

Comment: I've tried and tested different versions. All seem to pose problems. In the end I just switched to the more specific $.Post ajax function. That seemed to do the trick, but thanks!